# Div в одну строку с input

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```
<div id="panel-form">
<h1>Управление главной страницей</h1>
<fieldset>
<center>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width:430px" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<col class="col1" style="width: 45px;">
<col class="coln" style="width: 65px;">
<col class="col2" style="width: 35px;">
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>Тема:</td>
<td>
<select name="select">
<option value="1">Обычная</option>
<option value="2">Новогодняя</option>
<option value="3">День Рождения</option>
<option value="4">Хэллоуин</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><button onclick="call2()">Применить</button></td>
</tr>
</form>
<form action="javascript:void(null);" id="closed" method="post">
<tr>
<td>Состояние:</td>
<td>
<select name="closed" id="closed" onchange="doload(this.value);">
<option id="opened" value="0">Открыта</option>
<option id="closed" value="1" selected="selected">Закрыта</option>
</select>
<div id="countdown" style="display:inline-block;">
<span class="days">00</span> / <span class="hours">00</span>:<span class="minutes">00</span>:<span class="seconds">00</span>                                        
</div>
<input type="text" name="date" size="20" style="margin-top:5px" id="date" value="<?php printf("%s", $interval) ?>"></td><td><button onclick="call3()">Применить</button><button style="margin-top:3px" onclick="current()">Текущая</button></td></tr></table></form>
</center>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы `<div id="countdown">` был в одну строчку в `<select name="closed">`?

Сейчас это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `div` по своей сути не создан для того, чтобы находиться в одной строке с другими элементами.

Comment: задайте обоим элементам стиль `display:inline-block;`. А также убедитесь, что в ширину места хватает для обоих...